# Excel changes comma to dot even when cell is formatted as text

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel spreadsheet in MS Office 365 Business version 1703
and I typed a number string "123,456" with a comma separator in one of the cells.
Under right click -> Format cells... the category "Text" is chosen.
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot1]

However, if I open the underlying .xml file of the .xlsx file (unzip the .xlsx file and navigate to /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml) I find that the comma is transformed to a dot (i.e. the file stores "123.456" instead of "123,456")! 
See here:
[image: screenshot]

Is this what it is supposed to be like ? To me this is confusing because the "Text" category in Excel says that: "Text format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the cell. The cell is displayed exactly as entered."

My problem is that when parsing the file in java using Apache POI I get the number with the dot instead of the comma.

Comment: Have you checked your language settings on Excel? If so what are they?

Comment: Under Options -> Language -> Choose Editing Languages the default editing language is German. However, I would not expect this to play a role, because the "text" format cells are supposed to be not formatted ??

Comment: The format of the cell may already has been changed to text format. But that does not changes the present value automatically. The value will change only if someone changes something **after** the cell was formatted as text.

Comment: Yes! This is actually true, after changing the value of the text cell excel stores the cell content as string! Thanks Axel! This is really strange behavior though (??)